# Suppress exception while querying documentDB

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, azure-cosmosdb

I have a DocumentDB collection which has a huge number of documents. Some of them are invalid. I'm trying to asynchronously retrieve the documents based on some condition.

Below code is throwing exception when it founds an invalid document which satifies the condition but can not be mapped to `TEntity` (ex: some fields are `null`):

```
IDocumentQuery<TEntity> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(documentCollectionUri)
                                               .Where(c=>c.Name!="raju").AsDocumentQuery();

                List<TEntity> resultList = new List<TEntity>();
                while (queryable.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (TEntity t in await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<TEntity>()) //throws exception while parsing to TEntity
                    {
                        resultList.Add(t);
                    }
                }
```

I can set the [FeedOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.aspx) parameter to 1 and then put the try catch in `foreach` loop but this is not efficient approach (so many calls).

Any way to suppress the exception and fetch all the matching documents?

Comment: I think it depends where the exception is being thrown, is it possible to detect an invalid document before iterating through them?

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-generic CreateDocumentQuery and convert the Documents to TEntity yourself:

```
IDocumentQuery<TEntity> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery(documentCollectionUri)
    .Where(c=>c.Name!="raju")
    .Select(e => e as TEntity) // or whatever it takes to convert to TEntity without throwing
    .Where(e => e != null)
    .AsDocumentQuery();
```

Comment: tried, now getting "Unary operator 'TypeAs' is not supported." error for select()

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CreateDocumentQuery <T>` overload that takes a `SqlQuerySpec` and use the `SqlQuerySpec` to filter out the invalid documents. Something along these lines:

```
var query = new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT * FROM Documents d WHERE IS_DEFINED(d.property)");

IDocumentQuery<TEntity> queryable = 
    client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(documentCollectionUri, query)
          .Where(c=>c.Name!="raju")
          .AsDocumentQuery();
```

Comment: I have no control over the properties of object so can't use IS_DEFINED(d.property). it should be generic regardless of the property.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK uses Json.Net to deserialize internally. Did you try wrapping your not-nullable attributes with [NullValueHandling JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyPropertyLevelSetting.htm)?

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int? MyNotNullable { get; set; }
```

Comment: hmm.. this could solve the problem but then again I've to decorate all properties with this.

Comment: Only those that you know are breaking deserialization, not all, and your querying code keeps being Generic.